# What is the sum of this series involving factorial in denominator?

Tags: sequences-and-series

$$1 + \frac{1^2 + 2^2}{2!} + \frac{{1}^2 + {2}^2 + 3^2}{3!} + \cdots$$

I can't figure out how to do summations which involve a factorial term in the denominator. Please help.
This is a past year IITJEE question by the way.

Comment: Don't expect a trivial solution to this...

Comment: @Zach466920 Not trivial, perhaps, but definitely standard and leading to $$\frac{17e}6.$$

Comment: @Did Your right, I didn't think to sum the integers and then sum the terms. Still difficult, but yep now it looks pretty trivial.

Comment: See [Faulhaber's formulas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber's_formula#Examples).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT:

$$\sum_{r=1}^n\dfrac{1^2+2^2+\cdots+r^2}{r!}=\frac16\sum_{r=1}^n\dfrac{r(r+1)(2r+1)}{r!}=\frac16\sum_{r=1}^n\dfrac{r(r+1)(2r+1)}{r!}$$

Now for $r>0,$ $$\dfrac{r(r+1)(2r+1)}{r!}=\dfrac{(r+1)(2r+1)}{(r-1)!}$$

Let $(r+1)(2r+1)=2(r-1)(r-2)+a(r-1)$

Set $r=2$ to get $a$

Now, $$e^x=\sum_{r=0}^\infty\dfrac{x^u}{u!}$$